# How to load Array Data into Vuetify Select Input

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I'm trying to show "locations" in a vuetify select component, but my current code renders "[object Object]" instead of Location 1, Location 2, etc.

My select component:

```
<v-select
:items="locations"
v-model="location"
label="Choose Location"
bottom
autocomplete
></v-select>
```

Locations:

```
locations () {
  return this.$store.getters.getLocationsForEvent(this.event.id)
}
```

Vuex Getter:

```
getLocationsForEvent: (state) => (id) => {
  return state.loadedLocations.filter(function (location) { 
    return location.eventId === id; 
  });
}
```

Here is a screenshot of what the location data looks like:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Give an example of the data returned by the function `getLocationsForEvent`.

Comment: I added a screenshot of actual data

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For custom objects you have to specify the `item-text`. The `item-text` is **what each option will display**.

From your screenshot, for instance, `title` is a possible property:

```html
<v-select
:items="locations"
v-model="location"
label="Choose Location"
item-text="title"
bottom
autocomplete
></v-select>
```

Demos below.

Without `item-text`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      location: null,
      locations: [
        { id: "1111", manager: 'Alice',  title: 'Water Cart 1' },
        { id: "2222", manager: 'Bob',    title: 'Water Cart 2' },
        { id: "3333", manager: 'Neysa',  title: 'Water Cart 3' }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.0.10/dist/vuetify.min.css'>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.0.10/dist/vuetify.min.js'></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-select
        :items="locations"
        v-model="location"
        label="Choose Location"
        bottom
        autocomplete
        >
      </v-select>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

With `item-text`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      location: null,
      locations: [
        { id: "1111", manager: 'Alice',  title: 'Water Cart 1' },
        { id: "2222", manager: 'Bob',    title: 'Water Cart 2' },
        { id: "3333", manager: 'Neysa',  title: 'Water Cart 3' }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.0.10/dist/vuetify.min.css'>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.0.10/dist/vuetify.min.js'></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-select
        :items="locations"
        v-model="location"
        label="Choose Location"
        item-text="title"
        bottom
        autocomplete
        >
      </v-select>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use two properties? Something like title and manager?

Comment: @KeinGenie Not that I'm aware of. I think in that case you would have to create a derived property (result of the calculation using title and manager) and use that property as `item-text`.

Answer (score 1):

implemeneted a watch to have a low level Array of objects

```
watch: {
    groupInfo: function(groupInfo) {
      if (groupInfo.teams !== undefined) {
        var newArray = [];
        for (var key in groupInfo.teams) {
          var obj = groupInfo.teams[key];
          newArray.push(obj);
        }
        console.log("wagwan" newArray)
        this.teams = newArray;
      }
    }
  },
```