# Vuejs Vuetify how to access properties of object in v-select

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

My use case.

1. I got an array of objects from a back-end api.
2. I want to render those objects in a `v-select`

This is my code.

```html
<v-select
  :items="categories"
  name="category"
  label="Select a category"
  v-model="category"
  v-validate="'required'"
>
</v-select>
```

But it gives me the output.

[image]

**But I wants objects name property to be display in the** `v-select`

We would do this in vanilla Vue.js

```html
<li v-for="cat in categories" :key="cat.name">{{cat.name}}</li>
```

But here with vuetify we can't do this.

```
:items="categories.name"
```

Vuetify documentation

> Can be an array of objects or array of strings. When using objects,
> will look for a text and value field. This can be changed using the
> item-text and item-value props.

What they actually mean by `item-text` and `item-value`
How do I achieve this using `item-text`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load Array Data into Vuetify Select Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469589/how-to-load-array-data-into-vuetify-select-input)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

In Vuetify 3 you can pass your object's attribute name to the [`item-title` property](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-item-title):

```html
<v-select
  ...
  item-title="name"
  ...
/>
```

In Vuetify 2 [the property is named `item-text`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-item-text) rather than `item-title`.

Comment: with this, the select show the text to show but the model get the only text as value but not the entire object; what can be done if i want to put the full object as value of the model?

Comment: If you want the whole object, you can add the option return-object to v-select.

Answer (score 11):

I'd seen a similar solution on an example on codepen, but for some reason it did not work to merely assign the "name" to my item-text. Adding single quotes around the name attribute, thus making it a string, is what worked for me (but I don't know why that is):

```html
<v-select v-if="categories"
  :items="categories"
  :item-text="'name'"
  :item-value="'name'"
  v-model="selectedCategory"
  name="selectedCategory"
  label="Select categories"
  solo
  dark
>
</v-select>

<script> ...
categories: [
  { name: "test", path: "test" },
  { name: "test1", path: "test1" }
],
</script>
```

Comment: probably  because of ":" instead of :item-text it should be item-text

Comment: Use either :item-text="'name'" or item-text="name",
Not :item-text="name" or item-text="'name'"

Answer (score 7):

For those still looking, the item-name and item-value props are used to specify what value to return for the name and value from the item. If you want to display only the name, but keep the entire object as the value, the return-object prop will return the entire object in the v-model.

Check out the documentation at: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#custom-text-and-value

```
<v-select :items="categories" v-model="category" name="category"
v-validate="'required'" item-text="name" return-object label="Select a category"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for me it worked:

<v-select v-if="categories"
  :items="categories"
  :item-title="'name'" //alter here item-text to item-title
  :item-value="'name'"
  v-model="selectedCategory"
  name="selectedCategory"
  label="Select categories"
  solo
  dark
>
</v-select>

<script> ...
categories: [
  { name: "test", path: "test" },
  { name: "test1", path: "test1" }
],
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: item-title just saved me. i tried using item-text but it does not work for me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

For **Vuetify 2.x** use `<v-slot:item>` slot to customize the list and `<v-slot:selection>` to customize the selection. [check v-select slot list in the docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#slots)

```html
<v-select
  :items="categories"
  name="category"
  label="Select a category"
  v-model="category"
  v-validate="'required'"
>

  <template v-slot:item="{item}">
    {{item.name}}
  </template>    
  <template v-slot:selection="{item}">
    {{item.name}}
  </template>
</v-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

To be clear here's with script

```html
<template>
  <v-select 
    outlined
    :items="areas"
    v-model="area"
    name="area"
    item-text="text"
    label="Area"
    return-object
  ></v-select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
     area: { text: 'area', disabled: false, status: false },
     areas: [
       { text: 'Pre-op', disabled: false },
       { text: 'Operational', disabled: false },
       { text: 'USDA', disabled: false },
     ],
  }),
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).