# How to get an object rather than a single value when clicking on a v-select item?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

My `v-select`'s data is an array of objects. For each item, the `value` is one property and the `text` for that item is a different property. However I really need to retrieve both, not just the `value`.

So I guess I need to retrieve the object. Is it possible?

**V-select code**:

```
<v-select
  :items="projects"
  v-model="project"
  item-text="projectName"
  item-value="projectId"
  solo
></v-select>
```

**This is how the array of items is populated (in mounted hook)**:

```
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  let data = {
    'projectId': doc.id,
    'projectName': doc.data().name,
    'clientId': doc.data().clientId
  }
  this.projects.push(data);
});
```

Comment: add `return-object` prop.

Comment: Gosh yeah I just spotted that, I'm so used to being frustrated with the docs that I end up not bothering looking into it. You can make an answer so I can accept if you like

Comment: Not sure if it was asked before tho? Perhaps question title could be reworded to something that users are likely to search for?

Comment: Related (but not duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51296834/vuejs-vuetify-how-to-access-properties-of-object-in-v-select

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Add `return-object` prop:

```
<v-select return-object>
```

See docs:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-return-object