# Vuetify select component and graphql query

Tags: vuejs2, graphql, vuetify.js

I am learning vue/vuetify and graphql and I am using vue-apollo plugin in my small app. I have created a component that contains a vuetify select dropdown that is supposed to make a call to my local graphql instance and pull a list of categories. I get back a result from my api but in the dropdown it shows [Object object] as the dropdown items. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
<template>
<v-col cols="12" sm="6">
<v-select :items="cats" label="Income Category*" required> </v-select>
</v-col>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import Vue from "vue";
  import gql from "graphql-tag";

 export default Vue.extend({
    apollo: {
      incomeCategories: gql`
        query getCategories {
          incomeCategories {
             id
             incomeCategoryName
        }
      }
   `,
  },
  data: function() {
    return {}
  }
});
```

The vuetify select component item prop expects an array which is fairly obvious from the documentation but how do I get my results to show properly. Below is the signature of the type for incomeCategory:

```
type IncomeCategory {
  createdAt: DateTime
  id: String!
  incomeCategoryName: String!
  incomes: [Income]
  updatedAt: DateTime
}
```

And I am interested in id and incomeCategories only. Again can someone help me with this?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51296834/vuejs-vuetify-how-to-access-properties-of-object-in-v-select

Comment: @Paul this is it! I will mark this as the correct answer